# DataGrid binding to List<int?>

Tags: wpf, 2-way-object-databinding

I need suggestions on the best middle layer between the WPF DataGrid control and an underlying object of type `List<int?>` . Obviously I can't easily connect the two directly, as the DataGrid wants to bind to collection of objects with get/set properties, and I've had issues with the 'Value' property of a nullable int object not being found by a DataGrid column binding source.

The original data source has to remain as a `List<int?>`, and I'm trying to leverage the auto add/delete/edit features that DataGrid gives you, so that the two-way data binding is persisted to the original `List<int?>` source.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Post the code you have.  You will most likely need to use a converter to deal with null.

Comment: I was hoping to get some good solid ideas first before coding. The main issue I am having with experimental code is that converters are never called since the DataGrid is unable to bind correctly to collections of type int? ( the class System.Nullable.) I believe that the int? is being boxed/unboxed to the real int value upon binding attempts and then the "Value" property on an int? is gone, I am left with just the primitive int32 object.

Answer (score 2):

Mmm i believe you programm this in C# no?

Ok, to connect a DataGrid to Int the easy way is

Declare the Class or DataGrid(Variable, Functions or some)

```
List<int> int_Data;

int_Data = new List<int>(); 
int_Data.Add(DataGrid);

//Now, declare the DataGridColumn or Row and call this...

BindingList<Type> type = new BindingList<Type>();

type.Add(int_Data);
```

Its a simple example, sorry for errors ;)

Bye!

Comment: The question is int? nullable

Comment: For that was the question.  Ask SoConfused.

Comment: Sorry, my english is soo bad, but i try to say...

the Int is Null for default

Comment: No int is not null by default.  Try this code and you will get a compiler error.  int i; System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(i.ToString());  This will also throw an error i = null;

Answer (score 0):

Then post your experimental code that is failing.

Start with a TextBox and a converter and then use what you learn on DataGrid.  What comes out of an empty TextBox is NOT a null but rather a string empty so when you try and bind string empty directly to Int? you get a casting error.   You need to use a converter for string empty to null and null to string empty.